# Can you find error in this code for Palindrome Partitioning problem https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-partitioning/

Tags: c++, algorithm

Can you please help find the error. I am pushing temp which is vector<vector> type in dp[i], it is showing error. Can you help pointing out the error.

```
Line 54: Char 14: error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'
       dp[i].push_back(vv);
       ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
      ^
1 error generated.
```

```
class Solution {
public:
    void debug(vector<string> v){
        cout << "[";
        for(auto x : v) cout << x <<  ' ';
        cout << "]";
    }
    bool palin(string &s){
        int lo = 0, hi = s.length()-1;
        while(lo < hi){
            if(s[lo++]!=s[hi--]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    vector<vector<string>> partition(string s) {
        vector<vector<string>> ret;
        int n = s.length();
        if(n == 0) return ret;
        // dp[i] will store the partitioning sets for s[i:] prefix. 
        vector<vector<vector<string>>> dp(n);
        dp[n-1].push_back({{s.substr(n-1)}});
        for(int i = n-2; i >= 0; i--){
            vector<vector<string>> temp;
            for(int j = i; j < n; j++){
                string sub = s.substr(i, j-i+1);
                cout << sub << ' ';
                if(palin(sub)){
                    if(j+1 < n){
                        for(auto v : dp[j+1]){
                            
                         vector<string> temp1;
                         temp1.push_back(sub);
                            debug(v);
                            debug(temp1);
                            temp1.insert(temp1.end(), v.begin(), v.end());
                            debug(temp1);
                            temp.push_back(temp1);
                        }
                    }else{
                        temp.push_back({sub});
                    }
                }
            }
          
            vector<vector<string>> vv = temp;
            
            dp[i].push_back(vv);
        
        }
        return dp[0];
        return ret;

    }
};
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a comment in the code where you get the error. And also please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* output into the question (it often contains informational notes or hints that can be used to deduce the cause of the error and how to fix it).

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `dp` is `vector<vector<vector<string>>>` (And I guess that's the C++ equivalent of a three star programmer in C), so `dp[i]` is `vector<vector<string>>`. That's a vector that contains elements of type `vector<string>`, but you try to push `vector<vector<string>>`.

Comment: @churill That looks like an answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch That's what the compiler said, just in human language ;) I got no clue what would be the solution for it. On the other the  question was only to find the erorr, not to solve it ... so :D

Comment: @churill Exactly. If you make an answer I promise to give it a "safety-upvote". ;-) And note that I tried to find exactly what you wrote and could not phrase it. So it will be an honest upvote, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is all your compiler gave you, but here's the full error message I got:

```
main.cpp: In member function 'std::vector<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > Solution::partition(std::string)':
main.cpp:53:31: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::push_back(std::vector<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >&)'
   53 |             dp[i].push_back(vv);
      |                               ^
```

In human tounge that is:

`dp` is `vector<vector<vector<string>>>` and `dp[i]` is `vector<vector<string>>`. That's a `vector` that contains elements of type `vector<string>`, but you try to push `vector<vector<string>>`

Maybe you meant just `dp.push_back(vv);`? But I don't really get what your code is supposed to do without further explanation.

Comment: Thanks. That solved the error. I wanted to make vv the ith element in dp. The correction was dp[i] = vv; instead of dp[i].push_back(vv);